# Swift - como fixar em LandscapeLeft uma tela?

Tags: swift, mobile

O app possui 4 telas sendo que, apenas uma deve ficar fixa em LandscapeLeft. As outras ficam em Portrait..

Na aba **General** Configurei desta forma.

## General:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em **Objective-C** consigo forçar desta forma:

## Solução em Objective-C:

**.h**

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cristian,

No método viewDidLoad() coloque:

```
let mode = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(mode, forKey: "orientation")
```

E sobrescreva:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Para que a tela não volte para retrato, por exemplo, sobreescrever o método shouldAutorotate(), retornando false.

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Espero ter ajudado. Não sei se existe uma forma mais inteligente e automática.

Comment: Desta forma ele vai pra landscape, mas ele não impede que eu volte para Portrait.

Comment: E se você sobreescrever o shouldAutorotate? exemplo:  override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

Comment: Já estava fazendo isso, agora funcionou! Obrigado.

Comment: @CristianCotrena legal! Editei a pergunta acrescentando o shouldAutorotate.

Comment: Tive que sobrescrever value por mode para funcionar :)

Comment: @CristianCotrena eu vi :-) desculpe, estava como "value" e substitui por mode na hora de responder e esqueci de colocar na linha debaixo ;-P obrigado pela edição!